# Hide siblings when another dropdown is opened

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I'm fairly new to .js and have been working on a dropdown nav menu. I've got most of it functioning, but I was asked to include a specific snippet for the menu activation.

I'd like to figure out how to make the other subnav items hide or scroll up when a different subnav is opened.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<div id="nav_mob">
  <div id="nav-toggle"><span></span></div>
  <div class="dropdown_mob">
    <ul>
      <a class="dropdown_btn">
        <li>Overview</li>
      </a>
      <div class="subnav_mob">
        <ul>
          <a href="#"><li>Introduction</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li>Research</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li class="padded">Planning &amp; Preparation</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li>International</li></a>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <a class="dropdown_btn"><li>Profile</li></a>
        <div class="subnav_mob">
          <ul>
            <a href="#"><li>My Account</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>My Cart</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Check Out</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Log Out</li></a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <a class="dropdown_btn"><li>Search</li></a>
        <div class="subnav_mob">
          <ul>
            <li><div id="smallsearch"><input type="text"></div></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

the snippet I was given:

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown_btn');
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display == 'block') {
      dropdownContent.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = 'block';
    }
  });
}
```

and the fix I tried to implement:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown_btn').on('click', function() {
    var state = $('.dropdown_btn').is('.active');
    if(state) {

      $('.dropdown_btn').removeClass('active').next('.subnav_mob')
      .slideUp();
    } else {

      $('.dropdown_btn').addClass('active').next('.subnav_mob').slideDown();
      $.closest('.dropdown_btn').siblings('.dropdown_btn')
      .find('.dropdown_mob').slideUp().end();
      $.find('.dropdown_btn').not(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is that `$('dropdown_button')` selects every element with that same class, not just the one you clicked on. Operating on it will thus operate on every dropdown at once. You may have noticed that clicking one button causes every dropdown to open, and clicking another button causes them all to close again. This is why.

Your second problem is that `$.closest` is not a thing. If you press F12 and check out the console, you'll notice an error being thrown from that line, saying that '$.closest' is not a function. It's actually 'undefined', and attempting to invoke it as a function with `()` causes this error. This prevents any code after this point from being run, though even if you fix this that code still won't work for similar reasons. `$.find` is not a function, either, for example. `closest` and `find`, like `next` and `slideup`, are methods on jQuery instances, not on the global jQuery object itself.

This should work. Note that `$(this)` refers to the clicked element wrapped in a JQuery instance:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown_btn').on('click', function() {
    var state = $(this).is('active');
    if(state) {
        $(this).removeClass('active')
            .next('.subnav_mob').slideUp();
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active')
          .next('.subnav_mob').slideDown();
      $(this).siblings('.dropdown_btn').removeClass('active')
          .next('.subnav_mob').slideUp();
    }
  })
})
```

I would recommend stepping through each call in this, compare it with the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/), to really make sure you understand it. I'd also might recommend trying to do it without jQuery-- using the native DOM API like the original snippet was doing. Such an exercise might be frustrating, but valuable.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I wasn't really ready to deal with the JQuery aspect of this whole thing and didn't really know what the `$` did  to the code. I had started pulling all of the `(this)` instances out because I thought I had somehow botched the targeting somewhere down the line.